# Regex for remove citation

Tags: regex, replace

I searched regex for removing citation from text ( they sound strange from voice reading software ).

I want to remove from text all citation in form

> (Author, 2000), (Author, in press)

and

> (Author something, something 2004, Author2 2005)

But in same time not remove normal text in braces, and for ex. (Figure 3) (which might be helpful for reader).

Example of text with citations: http://journal.frontiersin.org/article/10.3389/fnhum.2014.00114/full

Comment: site I used for checking http://www.regexpal.com/

Answer (score 3):

I've better:

```
\([^\)]*,[^\)]*\)
```

See <kbd>[LiveDemo](https://regex101.com/r/xT7eS6/1)</kbd>

Comment: Selected (i.e., the ability to switch between different roles and perform well in both) and (eg. fada) so not that optimal. Still not bad try. Optimal would return all figures and real braces sentence, and eliminate only citation.

Comment: @SkorpEN then you can't. Since `(Author, in press)` will have the same signature than `(i.e., the ability to switch between different roles and perform well in both)`

Answer (score 0):

I use the one I found [here](https://electricarchaeology.ca/2016/06/16/regex-to-grab-your-citations-provided-youre-sensible/):

```
r"([A-Z][\w\-]+ )?\((\D*\d{4}(: ?[\d\-]*)*(, \d{4}(: ?[\d\-]*)*)*;?)*\)"
```

Answer (score -1):

Best i found is

```
[\(].?[^\)]*?[\d\d\d\d]{1}.*?[\)]{1}
```

It might not be optimal, because it selects (1) which in some cases might not be what reader want, still it is close to optimum.

Comment: The idea is here (searching a year before the closing bracket) but your pattern doesn't make sense. take a look at a regex tutorial. Using regex101.com will give your more informations about what you have written.